# Write/Edit content in an HTML/Javascript page

Tags: php, regex

I want to make an app where a user can generate an HTML/Javascript page after filling a form.

Exp:

in the form the user enters theses values :
width : 400
height : 500 
title : my title
domain : http://www.mydomain.com
...

In the HTML page i generate the width css property of a certain div will have the value 400px, same for the height, another div with a certain class will have the value of the title field.
And finally a javascript variable will have the value  of the domain field.

Until here it's quite easy to do, the problem comes up when a user wants to edit theses values is it possible to update the created file without regenerating it (i don't want to overwrite eventual manual changes the user could have made) ?

The only solution i can think of right now is using some sort of special comments:

```
<div class="title"><!-- @title -->my title<!-- @end title --></div>
for javascript/css: 
var domain = /* @domain */"mydomain"/* @end domain */;
```

Is this the best way? and if so how would i go about changing theses values?

Comment: Had you considered making the page dynamic, rather than generating static HTML?

Comment: Look into something like [knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com).

Comment: @Slukehart the page will be used on an other server and needs to be in HTML only

Comment: @tenub can you please explain more what's your idea?

Comment: @Youssef, visit the website I linked. If you bothered to read or look at any examples you wouldn't be confused.

Comment: @tenub i read the examples (i already know what knockout.js is used for) my guess is you're talking about the templating component, that is  ok for HTML but how does it enable replacing javascript/css values?

Comment: @Youssef, it is a JS framework, so any JS variable can be created/changed with it. CSS values can be changed as well via inline or changing classes with the style and css bindings respectively. You could even go so far as to create a computed observable that generates a valid CSS string and bind it to any HTML element(s).